# Failed with 500 status - angular js

Tags: angularjs, iis-6, asp.net-web-api

I've project with angular js and web api. My project hosted in IIS6.2. Based on some links I've added mime type json to the IIS.

When I am trying to throw error on exception it's working perfectly. But when I return response object on success it return with 500 status.

Actually, It works fine in the local not in the IIS after i hosted.

I've tried like,

- without accept verbs
- [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
- [AcceptVerbs("Post","Get")]

When I execute my project from local, It execute perfectly without any error.
But when I execute from server, I am getting,

```
 Failed with 500 status
```

Here I got confused because, the data are saved perfectly. But got error failed with 500 status.

From web api, I got the following issue like,

```
<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>
```

**Code:**
**Web Api**

```
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]



public HttpResponseMessage Signup(RegisterModel registerModel)
        {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            BLUser.UpdateUser(User);

            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK) or Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response.Content = new StringContent(errorMessage);
                response.ReasonPhrase = errorMessage;
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

                throw new HttpResponseException(response);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

**Angular js**

```
$http({
                method: "post",
                url: "/api/Common/Signup",
                data: user
            });
```

Can you please provide a solution to solve this ?

Comment: you are returning an exception `return new HttpResponseException(response);` and yet you expect and 200 OK status?

Comment: Sorry mistakenly mentioned. I am not returning, I am just throwing the exception. I've edited the question. Please look again my question. Sorry. throw new HttpResponseException(response);

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with AngularJS, while the HTTP error 500 is for an Internal Server Error.

Comment: this is a backend error as @Sapher said. However, this may help you, if you are using Chrome, go to the developer toolbar, and click on network tab to see what could that error be. You may try this a couple of times with different data to investigate more.

Comment: But in local, I didn't get this error. That's why confused..

Comment: On exception I am returning httpResponse exception, If it succeeded then I am returning 200 ok status..

Comment: Could you please post complete method definition? Looks like you are trying to post data from angularjs whereas service is supporting only get.

Comment: Can you check the question again please ?

Comment: @JeevaJsb  i think it is using System.Web.MVC for `AcceptVerbs` annotation , don't use `[AcceptVerbs("Post")]` directly, instead use `[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` , as per me there is something bad happening on server side. angular doesn't causing any issue.

Comment: @JeevaJsb  are you trying to do CORS?, then you need to enable CORS inside web API.

Comment: It would be good to check the actual code, just in case somethings missed in the transcription to this question. For example you use the variable `errorMessage` but it is never declared nor passed in. Is your `MapHttpRoute` in `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` changed from the default at all?

Comment: It may also be worth checking locally on a different machine, and checking through any NuGet packages. When I have had Web API code that worked locally but not when deployed to Azure it turned out to be a references issue.

Comment: Can you change your deployed API web.config to include the raw 500 error. Under `<system.web><customErrors mode="Off" />...</system.web>` ?

Comment: I've got one exception. But I didn't throw that exception. Just I catched. Because of that I got this exception message.. I've implemented log and found the issue.  Now it's working. Sorry forgot to post this comment as soon as I found.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this probably won't solve the issue, you seem to be missing the 'location' header from the response. I'm not sure of your setup, but a browser usually goes to the location of the new resource if it's been provided.

I think the property you need to set is response.Headers.Location

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using curl or postman. Before you test it with angular try testing it using [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) before angular.

Also **data: user** user objects properties must match the properties in **RegisterModel** else .NET won't be able to parse json and convert it to class which will through ERROR.